# Ti.Barcode Rotation issue

Tags: ios, titanium-modules

I'm having an issue with the `Ti.Barcode` module where when the device is rotated the barcode scanning screen rotates also, even though device orientation is set to `Ti.UI.PORTRAIT` in the `tiapp.xml` file

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Module: `Ti.Barcode v1.8.3`

Titanium `SDK: 3.2.2.GA`

Image below:

[image: Rotation Screenshot]

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found solution? I have Titanium 3.2.3 and the overflow elements are not showing on the screen.
I use `Barcode.allowRotation = false;` but this is not afecting anything

Comment: Haven't had any luck as of yet. I've submitted a bug report to them (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMODOPEN-424), hopefully they come back with something useful.